# Selecting html content with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to grab the text from within a span tag that is also within a p tag. How can I do this?

Example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p> Hiking <span> 1 </span> </p>
</div>
```

So all that should be returned is:

```
1
```

What I've tried:

```
$(".wrapper").click(function() {
    var num= $(this).html();
    alert(num);
}):
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$(".wrapper").click(function() {
    var num= $(this).find('span').text();
    alert($.trim(num));
});
```

Basically you want to select the text of the span element inside the wrapper, so use `.text` and `find` on your html. Doing `$(this).html()` will just give you the string repro of the html of wrapper entirely, instead you just need to selectively select the element's (target) text.
Similarly incase your html is like this and you want to avoid selection of nested span:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p> Hiking <span> 1 <span> Do not select this </span></span> </p>
</div>
```

You could do:

```
 var num= $(this).find('>p > span')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: You can also use the optional `context` parameter instead of `.find()` and do `var num= $('span', this).text();` I think it looks a little cleaner.

Comment: @valverij Personal pref i believe and also i guess using find would be faster.

Comment: I wasn't really arguing one way or the other. Just providing an informational tidbit.

Comment: @valverij Yeah i know. Thats why i said it is personal pref and just gave an extra info based on my exp... Thats all... :) Cheers...